# How to even know what to look for when refactoring for dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Just read a couple articles about DI today and I am tasked to refactor a project to use AutoFac :) wonderful!

So for example here is a snapshot of one of the classes in my code:

```
public class LoginManager : ManagerBase
{
// stuff 

    public LoginModel LoadLoginPageData()
        {
            LoginModel model = new LoginModel();
 model.blahblah = "whateverrr"
}
}
```

So how do go about it?  From my learning I see a `new LoginModel()`  statement there so I am going to create an interface for it, pass it as a parameter to the constructor of this class ?

Comment: Is `LoginModel` a simple object that contains data only? Does it contain behavior? What kind of behavior? Is it intrinsic to the object itself? Or does it contain behavior that you might want to vary? What I am asking basically is: is it a [newable or an injectable](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/)?

Comment: @YacoubMassad I dunno ! I have to read that article you sent me first.  but if you just mean how it has been used, if I look for instances of its use in code Yes I see in some places we are calling "new" on it

Comment: I don't see any dependencies in this code?

Comment: @Nico : Why ? How LoginManager do you think is not dependant on LoginModel ? how do we decide?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, refactoring really depends on your current goals for your application. In this case, your method does depend on LoginModel, because your method needs an instance of a Login model to function. (This is what defines your dependency)

You could abstract your model out by making an interface or abstract class and then inject it into your constructor of your LoginManger, but that more or less falls in line with loose coupling.

This is an important distinction to make. You don't need loose coupling to implement dependency injection. Dependency injection is supposed to solve the problem of swapping out object dependencies during runtime or compile time. So it helps to have loose coupling.

In your specific example here you don't need to inject a LoginModel into the constructor of the class lest you're planning on use that same model instance throughout the class. If you're still trying to dependency injection, provided the rest of the LoginManger doesn't need to know about that LoginModel instance, you can get away with method injection. Again, you can inject a specific LoginModel instance without making an abstracted version of your model--unless you plan on swapping it out with similar but varying LoginModels.